# Query calendarView events that don't contain a specific singleValueExtendedProperties

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, office365, microsoft-graph-sdks, microsoft-graph-calendar

I have created some extended properties on some events, but I am trying to return all events that **don't** contain this extended property.

Is it possible to build this filter somehow?

I am trying to pass these filtering clauses, but none seem to work:

```
1. singleValueExtendedProperties/any(ep: ep/id eq '{extendedPropertyId}' and ep/value eq '')
2. singleValueExtendedProperties/all(ep: ep/id ne '{extendedPropertyId}')
3. singleValueExtendedProperties/any(ep: ep/id eq '{extendedPropertyId}' and ep/value eq null)
```

Just to exemplify, I have 2 possible events:

1. Has extended property, and it has a value
2. Doesn't have any extended property.

In my query, I am trying to fetch only 2, excluding any extended property

UPDATE:
I am running the following query in the /events endpoint, which works

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/calendars/{calId}/events?startdatetime=2022-09-14T15:07:31.041Z&enddatetime=2022-09-23T15:07:31.042Z&$expand=singleValueExtendedProperties($filter=id eq 'String {43a36491-c91c-4480-b9c1-8fc61c6e0f6e} Name IntegrationId')&$filter=singleValueExtendedProperties/any(ep: ep/id eq 'String {43a36491-c91c-4480-b9c1-8fc61c6e0f6e} Name IntegrationId' and ep/value eq null)
```

But when running agains the /calendarView endpoint, it returns zero results

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/calendars/{calId}}/calendarView?startdatetime=2022-09-14T15:07:31.041Z&enddatetime=2022-09-23T15:07:31.042Z&$expand=singleValueExtendedProperties($filter=id eq 'String {43a36491-c91c-4480-b9c1-8fc61c6e0f6e} Name IntegrationId')&$filter=singleValueExtendedProperties/any(ep: ep/id eq 'String {43a36491-c91c-4480-b9c1-8fc61c6e0f6e} Name IntegrationId' and ep/value eq null)
```

Answer (score 1):

A pattern you can use is

```
singleValueExtendedProperties/any(ep: ep/id eq '{extendedPropertyId}' and ep/value eq null)
```

eg

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/mailFolders('Inbox')/messages?$filter=singleValueExtendedProperties/any(ep: ep/id eq 'String 0x1042' and ep/value eq null)
```

If you want to use a Extended property within a Filter in a Calendar view then you need to expand it first (you don't need to do that when you are using the normal events endpoint). So something like

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/calendar/calendarView?startDateTime=2022-09-01T19:00:00Z&endDateTime=2022-09-10T19:00:00Z&$select=subject&$expand=singleValueExtendedProperties($filter=id eq 'String 0x0037')&$filter=singleValueExtendedProperties/any(ep: ep/id eq 'String 0x0037' and ep/value eq 'Cloud and Mobile Working Group')
```

Comment: Thanks for the response! I did try that, but that doesn't work. This query would filter out entities that doesn't have that property, but include the ones that have the property with a null value.

Comment: Apparently it does work, but only on /events endpoint and not on /calendarView endpoint, which would lead into a huge refactor on my side because calendarView calculates recurring events :(

Comment: If you want to use a Extended property within a Filter in a Calendar view then you need to expand it first (you don't need to do that when you are using the normal events endpoint). I've include an example in the answer (as it doesn't appear correctly in the comments)

Comment: Thank you very much, Glen. I am running expanded and filtered query. Different results between /event and /calendarView result. Something is happening internally and this specific filter doesn't work. And the events are not recurring nor calculated, so that is not the issue. I updated my answer with an example, and later on I might open a bug ticket with Microsoft.